# Upload apk to store gets warning message

Tags: android, build, google-play, build.gradle

When I try to upload the apk to store I get these warnings

Partially upgradable APK

**WARNING**

*Some users of this APK may not be able to upgrade to any of the new APKs added in this release*.

**CAUTION**

*Users that currently have APK with version code 53, which targets SDK 22 or lower, will be eligible to upgrade to this APK. However, once users upgrade to this APK, they will be unable to upgrade to APKs that target SDK 22 or lower.*

Following datas are my current build details

- **compileSdkVersion 26**
- **buildToolsVersion 26.0.2**
- **minSdkVersion 15**
- **targetSdkVersion 26**

This is my previous update details

- compileSdkVersion 25
- buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
- minSdkVersion 15
- targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: Post your both app-module level gradle files--previous release and current release, please.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes already I posted the previous and current gradle details

Comment: yes, but I wanted to check **version codes**.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes
Previous versionCode 83 and versionName "5.2.1"
Current   versionCode 87 and versionName "5.2.2"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This warning is because yoy have upgraded your api higher than 22 that means you have to handle some runtime permisions. The warning says that this is a one way switch i.e there is no way of coming back to targeting API 22 or earlier once you make the switch to the runtime permission model.The developer console is just confirming that you have done all the thing need for runtime permissions so no need to worry.

Comment: But what does the  warning message means ?
Some users of this APK may not be able to upgrade to any of the new APKs added in this release.

Comment: are you trying to upgrade multiple apks at a time??

Comment: No Multiple Apk's

Answer (score 3):

It is normal but in your case - you need to be careful since you target several levels higher.

> **Warning**: Users using previous build would not be able to install the
> update simply because of difference in permission models and higher
> compile - 26. So if you don't make sure that you handle new permission
> models and other functionalities, you may tend to lose part of your
> users.
>
> **Caution**: Users once they update to the new build will not be
> able to upgrade back to lesser build of the same App. This means once
> you publish your App in higher build successfully, you can't go back
> to lesser build targets in your next update. Make sure all your
> functionalities work in the new build before deploying.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Its simply ok.

Warning indicates that once you increase your target version higher than your previous target version then users get update to newer targeted version app. But then after they cant receive update for lower target version.

But make sure you have handled **Runtime Permission Model** Properly for all dangerous group permission.

**Rather than it does not affect your user base or nor your app functionality.**

*Happy Coding..*